# BorderContainer Corner Rounding Only At Top Or Bottom

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I need to round at only the top or bottom of a border container not all four corners, is their some CSS that I can use or do I have to create two new skins. I was reading their used to be a property for this for HBox back in the old days, is their not a property for BorderContainer now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With BorderContainer you can't. However, the visual effect you want to achieve can easily be created with SkinnableContainer and a custom skin. In fact BorderContainer is just a specific form of SkinnableContainer.

So instead of BorferContainer create a SkinnableContainer with property 'skinClass':

```
<s:SkinnableContainer left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
                      skinClass="my.app.skins.TopRoundedCornerSkin">
    <!--- your components go here --->
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

Then create the skin class TopRoundedCornerSkin.mxml like so:

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.SkinnableContainer")]
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Rect id="background" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
            topLeftRadiusX="10" topLeftRadiusY="10" 
            topRightRadiusX="10" topRightRadiusY="10">

        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xffffff" />
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Group id="contentGroup" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10" 
             minWidth="0" minHeight="0" />

</s:Skin>
```

On the background rectangle, we set 4 radius properties to create the rounded corner you need.